# SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pyspark-schema

When executing from within my *Jupyter Notebook* some cells containing some Spark commands (eg., some DataFrame.show() methods or some spark.sql select commands involving 6 million row DataFrames), I get the following sequence of **message errors**:

*Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling xxxx.showString.

SparkException: **Job aborted due to stage failure**.

Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: **Python worker failed to connect back**.

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out.*

How can I interpret them?
I work in a **local 8g Spark session**.

Comment: Get some other messages before the one _Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling xxxx.showString_. Something happened before.

Comment: No other messages before this.